# MongoDB Aggregate how to pair relevant records for processing

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I've got some event data captured in a MongoDB database, and some of these events occur in pairs.

Eg: DOOR_OPEN and DOOR_CLOSE are two events that occur in pairs

Events collection:

```
{ _id: 1, name: "DOOR_OPEN", userID: "user1", timestamp: t }
{ _id: 2, name: "DOOR_OPEN", userID: "user2", timestamp: t+5 }
{ _id: 3, name: "DOOR_CLOSE", userID: "user1", timestamp:t+10 }
{ _id: 4, name: "DOOR_OPEN", userID: "user1", timestamp:t+30 }
{ _id: 5, name: "SOME_OTHER_EVENT", userID: "user3", timestamp:t+35 }
{ _id: 6, name: "DOOR_CLOSE", userID: "user2", timestamp:t+40 }
...
```

Assuming the records are sorted on the timestamp, the _id: 1 and _id: 3 are a "pair" for "user1. _id: 2 and _id: 6 for "user2".

I'd like to take all these DOOR_OPEN & DOOR_CLOSE pairs per user and calculate the average duration etc. the door has been opened by each user.

Can this be achieved using the aggregate framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$lookup` and $group for achieving this.

```
db.getCollection('TestColl').aggregate([
{ $match: {"name": { $in: [ "DOOR_OPEN", "DOOR_CLOSE" ] } }},
{ $lookup:
       {
         from: "TestColl",
         let: { userID_lu: "$userID", name_lu: "$name", timestamp_lu :"$timestamp" },
         pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$userID",  "$$userID_lu" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$$name_lu", "DOOR_OPEN" ]},
                         { $eq: [ "$name", "DOOR_CLOSE" ]},
                         { $gt: [ "$timestamp", "$$timestamp_lu" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              },              
           ],
         as: "close_dates"
       }
},
{ $addFields: { "close_time": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$close_dates.timestamp", 0 ] }  } },
{ $addFields: { "time_diff": { $divide: [ { $subtract: [ "$close_time", "$timestamp" ] }, 1000 * 60 ]} } }, // Minutes
{ $group: { _id: "$userID" , 
    events: { $push: { "eventId": "$_id", "name": "$name",  "timestamp": "$timestamp" } },
    averageTimestamp: {$avg: "$time_diff"}
    }
}
])
```

Sample Data:

```
[
{ _id: 1, name: "DOOR_OPEN", userID: "user1", timestamp: ISODate("2019-10-24T08:00:00Z") },
{ _id: 2, name: "DOOR_OPEN", userID: "user2", timestamp: ISODate("2019-10-24T08:05:00Z") },
{ _id: 3, name: "DOOR_CLOSE", userID: "user1", timestamp:ISODate("2019-10-24T08:10:00Z") },
{ _id: 4, name: "DOOR_OPEN", userID: "user1", timestamp:ISODate("2019-10-24T08:30:00Z") },
{ _id: 5, name: "SOME_OTHER_EVENT", userID: "user3", timestamp:ISODate("2019-10-24T08:35:00Z") },
{ _id: 6, name: "DOOR_CLOSE", userID: "user2", timestamp:ISODate("2019-10-24T08:40:00Z") },
{ _id: 7, name: "DOOR_CLOSE", userID: "user1", timestamp:ISODate("2019-10-24T08:50:00Z") },
{ _id: 8, name: "DOOR_OPEN", userID: "user2", timestamp:ISODate("2019-10-24T08:55:00Z") }
]
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "user2",
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "eventId" : 2.0,
            "name" : "DOOR_OPEN",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-24T08:05:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "eventId" : 6.0,
            "name" : "DOOR_CLOSE",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-24T08:40:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "eventId" : 8.0,
            "name" : "DOOR_OPEN",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-24T08:55:00.000Z")
        }
    ],
    "averageTimestamp" : 35.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "user1",
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "eventId" : 1.0,
            "name" : "DOOR_OPEN",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-24T08:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "eventId" : 3.0,
            "name" : "DOOR_CLOSE",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-24T08:10:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "eventId" : 4.0,
            "name" : "DOOR_OPEN",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-24T08:30:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "eventId" : 7.0,
            "name" : "DOOR_CLOSE",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-24T08:50:00.000Z")
        }
    ],
    "averageTimestamp" : 15.0
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, but still doesn't achieve what I want. if there was another entry, say

```
{ _id: 7, name: "DOOR_CLOSE", userID: "user1", timestamp:ISODate("2019-10-24T08:50:00Z") }
```

then the two pairs for user 1 would be 

```
pair1: eventID 1 & 3 => dateDiff 10
pair2: eventID 4 & 7 => dateDiff 20
```

giving an average of 15. 

In the group stage, you are simply selecting the min DOOR_OPEN and max DOOR_CLOSE.

Comment: perfect. thanks a lot. that looks like exactly what I want. I was only aware of the simple lookups using the equality match. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#equality-match

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `$group` operator of the aggregate framework to group by userID and calculate the averages:

```
db.events.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$userID",
        averageTimestamp: {$avg: "$timestamp"}
    }
}]);
```

If you also want to discard any other event other than DOOR_OPEN or DOOR_CLOSED, you can add a filter adding a `$match` in the aggregate pipeline:

```
db.events.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $or: [{name: "DOOR_OPEN"},{name: "DOOR_CLOSE"}]
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$userID",
        averageTimestamp: {$avg: "$timestamp"}
    }
}]);
```

Comment: But the timestamps are not durations. The duration should be calculated by the delta of timestamps of the matching pair. And then I need to average the durations of all such pairs per user.